# Is there a way to document all the used definitions next the #include <header.h> file they are defined in?

Tags: c++, c

How can you list all externally functions/variables/types used within your program next to the header file `#include` they are defined in?

I am trying to achieve something like this...

```c
#includes <blah.h> // getBlah, BLAH_CONST, isBlah
```

**Why:**
I am maintaining some large and old C (and C++) libraries with many dependencies on other libraries. Each file can contain upwards of 50+ `#includes` and identifying what header file a specific function belongs to is difficult to identify. Also, due to unique circumstances traditional IDE's do not work many with our operating system and/or size of includes path is massive.

**Example:**

```c
// Currently 
#include <teama_dateinfo_accessor.h>
#include <teamb_calendar_accessor.h>

bool isLeapYear(year: int) {
  struct Year yearInfo = getYearInfo(year); // <- ?? where is this being defined
  return yearInfo.isLeapYear;
}
bool isTaxMonth(month: int) {
  struct Month monthInfo = lookUpMonth(month); // <- ?? where is this being defined
  return monthInfor.areTaxesDue;
}
```

```c
// Trying to Achieve 
#include <teama_dateinfo_accessor.h> // getYearInfo, Year
#include <teamb_calendar_accessor.h> // lookUpMonth, Month

bool isLeapYear(year: int) {
  struct Year yearInfo = getYearInfo(year);
  return yearInfo.isLeapYear;
}
bool isTaxMonth(month: int) {
  struct Month monthInfo = lookUpMonth(month);
  return monthInfor.areTaxesDue;
}
```

Inspired by JavaScript & Python syntax for `imports`.

```js
import { getYearInfo, Year } from 'teama_dateinfo_accessor';
```

```py
from teamb_calendar_accessor import lookUpMonth, Month
```

Comment: I'm aware of no such tool, but it would be possible to write a program that parses the headers and adds a suitable comment to source file that include it.  Also, it is common for headers to declare things that are not used by every program - you'll need to decide how you want to deal with such cases (e.g. do you want the comment to list symbols you don't use?).   Similarly, there are cases where some names are declared in multiple distinct headers, and cases where headers include each other.   Not sure if there is value in having such comments for standard headers.

Comment: C++ is hard to parse, so the tool you expect might hardly exist. I can't find it. Use a better IDE might help.

Comment: @LouisGo in the entirety, yes. A naive implementation to parse preprocessor definitions could get them 90% of what they need, and the remaining 10% can be flagged as "we haven't implemented this yet, go to file x, line y"

Comment: Do these headers come with documentation?  If so, you could build a json of `{ "header name" : [public definitions] , ... }`.  Then you could build a tool to parse your files and add the relevant comments.